# Why is the spectral radius of a matrix not a norm?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces, spectral-theory

It's a simple question that I expect will be closed as a duplicate, or answered with a link. That said, I've scoured the suggestions that came for my question title, as well as some relevant Wiki / math pages (even a few papers), and nothing really seems to treat this.

I feel that my understanding of eigenvalues and / or eigenvectors may be what is lacking, but from what I can tell, unless a matrix A = 0, then it will have at least one nonzero eigenvalue? Which would allow it to satisfy all of the conditions for a norm. Honestly a point in the right direction is all I'm looking for here.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the matrices
\begin{align}
A= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\ \ \text{ and } \ \ 
B= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

What is the spectral radius of $A-B$?

Comment: $$\text{spr}(A - B) = 0

Which violates the nonzero condition. Thanks! What was I missing in terms of intuition, here? Is there some content I should try and familiarize myself with, or was I just unlucky in not considering that particular example when I was trying out some test cases?

My course instructor seems a bit "spartan" in that he doesn't really tell us what we should be studying in order to be up to date, even though the course material is clearly predicated on things not covered in the prerequisites.